# Defining bean in xml without class attribute

Tags: spring, class, attributes

I am a newbie to the world of Spring. In an interview, it was asked if we can create a bean in XML without specifying the `class` (that is, the bean would only have an `id` attribute).  I did not have the answer to this. Please advise if we can create a bean in XML in Spring without specifying the class attribute and under which conditions we would normally do this.

Comment: If you are using a factory then you can do it, but still you will have to specify the factory bean and method

Comment: @ArunPJohny please provide a small example that will be helpful to completely grasp.Thanks in advance

Comment: refer documentation http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/springbeansdtd.html) makes it quite clear:

```
<!--
    Each bean definition must specify the fully qualified name of the class,
    except if it pure serves as parent for child bean definitions.
-->
<!ATTLIST bean class CDATA #IMPLIED>
```

[This section](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-child-bean-definitions) explains it in detail and provides useful examples.

Comment: Bilinski could you please explain in detail under which section we only specify the bean id only and not class name under bean inheritance section

Comment: I've attached a link to the Spring docs for your convenience. You'll find a simple example there (search for "inheritedTestBeanWithoutClass").

Comment: <bean id="inheritedTestBeanWithoutClass" abstract="true">
    <property name="name" value="parent"/>
    <property name="age" value="1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="inheritsWithClass" class="org.springframework.beans.DerivedTestBean"
    parent="inheritedTestBeanWithoutClass" init-method="initialize">
  <property name="name" value="override"/>
  <!-- age will inherit the value of 1 from the parent bean definition-->
</bean>

Comment: The preceding example explicitly marks the parent bean definition as abstract by using the abstract attribute. If the parent definition does not specify a class, explicitly marking the parent bean definition as abstract is required

Answer (score 0):

As described by Szymon, bean definition inheritance is one way. Schema based configuration is another way, [see](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#xsd-config-body-schemas-util). For example, taken from Spring's documentation,

```
<!-- creates a java.util.List instance with the supplied values -->
<util:list id="emails">
    <value>pechorin@hero.org</value>
    <value>raskolnikov@slums.org</value>
    <value>stavrogin@gov.org</value>
    <value>porfiry@gov.org</value>
</util:list>
```