# How can I use the simple class name in Spring beans?

Tags: java, spring

How can I use

```xml
<bean id="oneId" class="OneClass">
    <property name="prop" ref="anotherBean">
</bean>
```

instead of

```xml
<bean id="oneId" class="com.bla.bla.bla.OneClass">
    <property name="prop" ref="anotherBean">
</bean>
```

?

Is there a possibility to import a package?

There are a lot of classes from the same package and I'd like to make the XML file more readable.

Comment: Define your beans using Java config instead of defining them using XML. Or just use annotations and autowiring, to avoid defining them completely. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-annotation-config and http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you **cannot** use the simple class name instead of the fully qualified class name, as [this Stack Overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220957/defining-bean-in-xml-without-class-attribute) discusses (and q.v. [the Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/springbeansdtd.html) itself), unless your bean `oneId` serves only as a parent for child beans.

However, if you use annotations instead of the XML descriptor files, you can use the simple class name `OneClass` and allow the import statement to handle the messiness of the package name qualifier.